# MEF & correct decoupling of a N layered Domain Driven Design architecture

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control, mef

I've been reading the NLayered Domain Driven Design Architecture guide book by Microsoft and I want to implement MEF as my DI container.

I wanted to test MEF by creating 3 projects: ContractProject which only has the interface. ImplementationProject which has the class that implements this interface with the Export[typeof(Interface)] annotation. And a console app to test this.

According to the Dependency Injection principles, the high level layer should not reference the low level layer and vice-versa. They should both reference an abstraction layer (interface).

I tried applying this. The console app references the ContractsProject and the implementationProject references the ContractsProject. But MEF can't find the EXPORT class if there is no ImplentationProject dll in the assembly. I've seen a tutorial where they manually add the dll to the bin folder of the MainApp. The good thing is you can't directly access the implementation methods by avoiding 'Add reference' dynamically but I don't think that's the right thing to do since I have to manually add the dll each time it changes. And working with a NLayered Domain Driven Design architecture app I'm gonna need a lot of dlls.

Does it mean that MEF is not the correct tool I need for Dependency Injection? (The book uses Unity)

Here is the code:

```
namespace Contracts
{
    public interface ISampleContract
    {
        string DoSomething();
    }
}

namespace Implementation
{
    [Export(typeof(ISampleContract))]
    public class Sample : ISampleContract
    {
        public string DoSomething()
        {
            return "I did something ";
        }
    }
}
```

Program:

```
namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {
        [Import]
        public ISampleContract sample { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()),
            new DirectoryCatalog("."));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            container.ComposeParts(this);
            Console.WriteLine(sample.DoSomething());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't reference the Implementation dll in the main program, the ComposeParts() thing fails because it can't find the exports that matches the constraint... Is there a way around this without referencing the dll or should I entirely choose another DI tool? Like Unity for example?

**EDIT**
It works if I configure the post-build event on the Implementation project to copy its dll to my Console bin. I'm not sure if this is a good solution?

```
copy /Y "$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)Console\bin\Debug\$(ProjectName).dll"
```

Comment: BTW I'm not sure if MEF is the best choice as inversion of control container...

Comment: I'm just beginning to realize that. Seems like MEF doesn't offer the full functionalities of a DI container yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure visual studio is actually building Implementation.dll. Usually what happends if you build Console.dll only Console.dll and it's dependencies are build. Any DI framework will have this issue.

One way to fix this is go to solution -> properties -> Project Dependencies and mark the build dependencies there. (note, the dlls will be in their own projects bin directory, you might as a post-build step deploy them all to a plugins directory)

At a later stage you might or might not setup some more advanced tooling to independently build and deploy you implementation.dll (I would only do this in reasonable large projects or projects with specific plugin requirements)

**Edit**: The disadvantage of unity (and some others) is that it often evolves to creating a huge mapping file (forcing you to have both a build and a code dependency).

Comment: Marked the build dependencies but it still doesn't solve my problem. MEF can't find the Export marked class. All the dlls are in their own projects bin but MEF still can't find Implementation.dll if this one doesn't not exist in the console bin folder. Debugging the catalog, the loaded files contain only the Contract.dll file

Comment: It works if I configure the build output of my Implementation.dll to be the bin folder of my Console. Is this a good solution?

Comment: I would output all other projects to output in a "plugins" directory and then point the path of the DirectoryCatalog to that directory. (makes it easier to see what's separate and what not)

I've seen this often done by a post build step with xcopy. Although i'm personally not much a fan of that solution.

Comment: Yes thank you. I agree it's a rather annoying solution. I'd have to manually configure post-build events on each implementation project.

You said that using Unity would evolve to creating a huge mapping file. I think I'm going to test Unity and compare which solution is better.

Comment: Instead of using unity you could also just create a reference between the projects. Then you don't need to do anything else.
(and for unity you need to create the reference anyways)

Comment: So If I can't avoid the references thing, I'll just create a class library that references all the modules I need and point my DirectoryCatalog to it?